# Left Vlookup and Importrange

Tags: google-sheets-formula, vlookup

I have a left vlook up set up in my spreadsheet and it works perfectly fine. It looks like this:

=VLOOKUP(search key,{'Sheet 1'!$C$3:$C$1400,'Sheet 1'!$A$3:$A$1400},2,0)

I would like to transfer this to a completely different worksheet and combine it with importrange. This would be easy if the formula were for a regular Vlookup. However, since I have a left vlook up, I am struggling to find the right syntax.

This is what I have but it's not working:

=Vlookup(search key,importrange("Sheet URL",{"Sheet 1!$C$3:$C$1400","Sheet 1'!$A$3:$A$1400"}),2,0)

Can somebody help?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try moving columns with `QUERY`:

```
=VLOOKUP(
  search key,
  QUERY(
    IMPORTRANGE("Sheet URL", "Sheet 1!A3:C1400"),
    "SELECT Col3, Col1
     WHERE Col3 IS NOT NULL",
  ),
  2,
)
```